# Variable stick lengths and angles at nodes of building bricks

Tags: building

Is it possible to build 3D toys connecting several LEGO Bricks sticks/rods to make polyhedrons? Lengths and angles between sticks should be variable.

Answer (score 2):

You mean like [these lovely polyhedrons](http://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=51472)?

Comment: Yes, they look great! Can they be made to get fixed in any set position? Is it possible to make a user defined rigid net of  convex hull like Fuller domes?

Comment: There are several style of [hinges](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?pg=2&catString=22&catType=P) available. The first 5 listed on that link are nice, and adding Hinge Plate 1 x 4 to the mix might give you everything you need. Anyway, tons of hinges to explore...